# Sequelize: Error: Error: Table1 is not associated to Table2

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create the following associations using sequelize but I keep getting     the following error “Error: Error: customer is not associated to order!”. I have bi-directional associations according to what I found in the documentation. I am confused about what the problem could be because when I look into the database tables I can see the foreign keys.  For this example, I am trying to pull the order and customer associated with the particular order.  Technically, I could do three seaprate db pull but that seems inefficient as opposed to joins.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING(30), //remove
    password: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    emailaddress: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    firstname: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    middlename: DataTypes.STRING(30), //remove
    lastname: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    approve: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    roles: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    isactive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        this.hasMany(models.order);
      }
    }
  });

  user.hook('afterCreate', function(usr, options) {
      //hash the password

      return user.update({ password: passwd }, {
        where: {
          id: usr.id
        }
      });
  });

  return user;
};



'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var order = sequelize.define('order', {
    ponumber: DataTypes.STRING(30), //remove
    orderdate: DataTypes.DATE,
    shippingmethod: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    shippingterms: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    deliverydate: DataTypes.DATE,
    paymentterms: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    overridediscount: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    shippingaddress: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    shippingcity: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    shippingstate: DataTypes.STRING(20),
    shippingzipcode: DataTypes.STRING(10),
    isactive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        this.belongsTo(models.user);
        this.belongsTo(models.customer);
      }
  });

  order.hook('afterCreate', function(ord, options) {
      //generate po number

      return order.update({ ponumber: ponumbr }, {
        where: {
          id: ord.id
        }//,
        //transaction: options.transaction
      });
  });

  return order;
};


'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var customer = sequelize.define('customer', {
    customernumber: DataTypes.STRING(30), //remove
    customerspecificationid: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    customertypeid: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sportid: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    customername: DataTypes.STRING(20), //remove
    address: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    city: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    state: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    zipcode: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    ordercomplete: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    isactive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
      associate: function(models) {
          // associations can be defined here
        this.hasMany(models.order);
      }
  });

  customer.hook('afterCreate', function(cust, options) {
      //generate the customer number

        return customer.update({ customernumber: custnumber }, {
        where: {
          id: cust.id
        }
      });
  });

  return customer;
};


Here is the constructor and method inside of a repository class I want to join 

constructor(model){
    super(model.order);
    this.currentmodel = model;
}


findById(id){
    let that = this;
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            that.model.find({
                where: { id: id },
                include: [ that.currentmodel.customer, that.currentmodel.user ]
            })
            .then(function(order){
                resolve(order);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                reject(err);
            })
    });
}
```

I have reviewed the documentation and searched the internet looking for a fix to this issue but I am not finding any answers.  Could someone please shed some light on what I could be missing?

For the example above, I am trying to retrieve the user and the customer tied to the order record via the primary key.  All of the findBy scenarios I have found so far would be getting a list of orders tied to the customer and user.  What do I need to change in order to retrieve the order and customer whose foreign keys are tied to this order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably with how you are setting you association, kindly mention your strategy.

Following is working fine if you use the express index.js file setup and then query http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var customer = sequelize.define('customer', {
    customernumber: DataTypes.STRING(30), //remove
    customerspecificationid: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    customertypeid: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sportid: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    customername: DataTypes.STRING(20), //remove
    address: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    city: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    state: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    zipcode: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    ordercomplete: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    isactive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
      associate: function(models) {
          // associations can be defined here
        models.customer.hasMany(models.order);
      }
  });

  customer.hook('afterCreate', function(cust, options) {
      //generate the customer number

        return customer.update({ customernumber: custnumber }, {
        where: {
          id: cust.id
        }
      });
  });

  return customer;
};


'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var order = sequelize.define('order', {
    ponumber: DataTypes.STRING(30), //remove
    orderdate: DataTypes.DATE,
    shippingmethod: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    shippingterms: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    deliverydate: DataTypes.DATE,
    paymentterms: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    overridediscount: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    shippingaddress: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    shippingcity: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    shippingstate: DataTypes.STRING(20),
    shippingzipcode: DataTypes.STRING(10),
    isactive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        models.order.belongsTo(models.user);
        models.order.belongsTo(models.customer);
      }
  });

  order.hook('afterCreate', function(ord, options) {
      //generate po number

      return order.update({ ponumber: ponumbr }, {
        where: {
          id: ord.id
        }//,
        //transaction: options.transaction
      });
  });

  return order;
};

'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var user = sequelize.define('user', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING(30), //remove
    password: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    emailaddress: DataTypes.STRING(255),
    firstname: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    middlename: DataTypes.STRING(30), //remove
    lastname: DataTypes.STRING(30),
    approve: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    roles: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    isactive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        models.user.hasMany(models.order);
      }
    }
  });

  user.hook('afterCreate', function(usr, options) {
      //hash the password

      return user.update({ password: passwd }, {
        where: {
          id: usr.id
        }
      });
  });

  return user;
};
```

// index.js file where you shall associate the routes

```
var fs        = require('fs')
    , path      = require('path')
    , Sequelize = require('sequelize')
    , lodash    = require('lodash')
    , sequelize = new Sequelize('sequelize_test', 'root', 'root')
    , db        = {} 

  fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(function(file) {
      return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js')
    })
    .forEach(function(file) {
      var model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file))
      db[model.name] = model
    })

  Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
    if (db[modelName].options.hasOwnProperty('associate')) {
      db[modelName].options.associate(db)
    }
  })
  // sequelize.sync({force: true})
  module.exports = lodash.extend({
    sequelize: sequelize,
    Sequelize: Sequelize
  }, db)
```

Put the above db code in respective files in db folder or whatever you like to name it and then you can use your query

var db = require('./db');

```
db.order.find({
            where: { id: 0 },
            include: [ db.customer, db.user ]
        })
        .then(function(order){
            console.log(order)
        })
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks a million.  One more question, if you don't mind.  So far I have been adding the foreign keys by setting the property before I create or update the record, like '...id = '.  Is there a preferred method for doing this, or is this approach acceptable?

Comment: I did get your question that clearly, but if you already have the ids of the model you want to associate and you can use your method for creating records using id for simple association like one to many or one to one