# NodeJS Sequalize Table1 is not associated to Table2

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two tables table1 and table2. i want to get relational data. I gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101243/sequelize-error-error-table1-is-not-associated-to-table2) URL which is same as the my error but that solution is not work for me

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
var table1 = sequelize.define("table1", {
    table1Id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    image: {type: DataTypes.STRING},  
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            table1.belongsTo(models.table2, {
                onDelete: "CASCADE",
                foreignKey: {
                    name: "table2Id",
                    notEmpty: false
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
return table1;
};
```

and another is :

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
var table2 = sequelize.define("table2", {
    table2Id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    name: {type: DataTypes.STRING}, 
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            table2.hasMany(models.table1, {
                onDelete: "CASCADE",
                foreignKey: {
                    name: "table1Id",
                    notEmpty: false
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
return table2;
};
```

then in controllers:

```
models.table2.findById(req.params.id, {
        include: [{model: models.table1}] 

    }).then(function (data) {


    }).catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, function (err) {
        return res.status(422).send(err.errors);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message,"err.message")
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: err.message
        });
    });
```

and i got error that Table1 is not associated to Table2

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Or SQL Server? You're probably not using both.

Comment: i am using the mysql as a database

Comment: how do you call the associate method ? my guess is the associate method is not called properly with all the models in it

Comment: its working fine in one system and not working in another system so i confused

Comment: I have two different systems and its working in one system perfectly but not working on another so i think it should be problem with the schema only but not able to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are on sequelize >4
The way association are defined is changed.

Instead of defining association as

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model',
 { ... },
 { classMethods: { associate: function (model) {...} }
 });
```

They are now defined as

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', { ... });
 // Class Method
Model.associate = function (models) { ...associate the models };
```

This could also justify why it seems to work on one machine and not the other.

Comment: i have used same code in my application
somehow its not working in some systems and others are working